# Issue with removing the textbox shadow in jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I need one hidden text field in my page so I have created a text box of style hidden. It is not visible but the shadow is hiding. How can we  remove the shadow. Any suggestions.

```
<input class="noshadow" type="text" value="text" style="display:none;"/>
```

CSS

```
.noshadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add data-role="none" to the input:

```
<input data-role="none" type="text" value="text" style="display:none;"/>
```

This stops jQM from enhancing the input and it will truly be hidden.

**Even better** change the input type to hidden:

```
<input  type="hidden" value="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that shadow is not your problem but another item's display. Look it with inspect tool and see what is out of input.